# How to create sliding navigation/content pane with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was looking at googles site:

```
https://frightgeist.withgoogle.com/
```

How do you replicate the effect where you click on a navigation item (e.g. "Trending Locally") and both the navigation and the main content area "slides" in the direction of the option clicked (whether its left or right)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by combining 'tabs' and 'carousel' functionality from  [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)